# Recovering black listed tasktrackers in mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I have 5 node hadoop cluster. I have configured 10 mappers per node. While a MR job is running one of the hdfs nodes died. This eventually lead to blacklisting of that task tracker. After it is black listed and before the MR job finishes, If I fix the affected hdfs node is it possible to recover the task tracker from black listing?

I am using cloudera cdh 4.2 on ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

I was reading "Hadoop Definitive Guide" about tasktracker failures. I found this statement

"*Blacklisted tasktrackers are not assigned tasks, but they continue to communicate with the jobtracker. Faults expire over time (at the rate of one per day), so tasktrackers get the chance to run jobs again simply by continuing to run. Alternatively, if there is an underlying fault that can be fixed (by replacing hardware, for example), the tasktracker will be removed from the jobtracker’s blacklist after it restarts and rejoins the cluster.*"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain about Cloudera 4.2, but you can try the command

```
$ hadoop job -unblacklist <jobid> <hostname>
```

If you want to remove it from the global blacklist, try

```
hadoop job -unblacklist-tracker <hostname>
```

Both commands have to be run as the admin user.